# what is a controlId in react-bootstrap

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-bootstrap

I was just going through the [React-bootstrap form](https://react-bootstrap.github.io/components.html#forms) what is the use of `controlId` is it similar to `name` we use in legacy form?

```
<form>
    <FormGroup
      controlId="formBasicText" ---------------------->> what is the use?
      validationState={this.getValidationState()}
    >
      <ControlLabel>Working example with validation</ControlLabel>
      <FormControl
        type="text"
        value={this.state.value}
        placeholder="Enter text"
        onChange={this.handleChange}
      />
      <FormControl.Feedback />
      <HelpBlock>Validation is based on string length.</HelpBlock>
    </FormGroup>
  </form>
```

Answer (score 52, accepted):

You can find it [here in the v3 docs](https://react-bootstrap-v4.netlify.app/components/forms/#form-group-props):

> Sets id on `<FormControl>` and `htmlFor` on `<FormGroup.Label>`.

Basically it's the input's `id` and the label's `for` attribute.

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the answer Sagiv b.g. I am just providing the updated URL 
https://react-bootstrap.github.io/components/forms/#form-group-props.